# Filter value contained in array in jq

Tags: json, jq

I want something like

```
jq 'select(.x in [2,4])' <<<'[{"x":1}, {"x": 2}, {"x": 3}, {"x": 4}]'
[{"x": 2}, {"x": 4}]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an efficient solution that has the advantage of also being simple and concise:

```
[2,4] as $list
| map(.x as $x | select( any($list[]; . == $x )))
```